# What is the overhead for an array in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, array

What is the additional overhead of an array compared to a normal column of that same datatype? In other words, if an array will almost always have one value in it, how much space would I be "wasting" by using an array instead of a normal column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check that using `pg_column_size()`:

```
select pg_column_size(1::integer) as int_size, 
       pg_column_size(array[1]::integer[]) as array_size
```

returns:

```
int_size | array_size
---------+-----------
       4 |         28
```

So the overhead is substantial for just a single value.

Comment: So would it be better to use a foreign key instead? The overhead for that would be a join, and two 4-byte integers for primary key if I'm not mistaken. In other words, instead of a one-time column overhead, it'd be a (smaller?) overhead for each row. What do you think?

Comment: @DavidTan: I can't put it better then [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) does: "*searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  But if you think the storage overhead of an array is bad, try the storage overhead of an additional 2-column table.

Answer (score 3):

## Indexing requirements

It's also important to consider indexes. If you create an index on an `int` type you'll likely use the natural comparison operators which will work on the default b-tree index. However, if you have an `int[]` type you have [new operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) Because an `int` type presumably doesn't work, you likely won't want `=` or you would just use the int type. That is to say, you *probably* don't want `arrayCol = array[2948]`, or you would just use `intCol = 2948`.

```
CREATE TABLE test AS (
  SELECT x::int AS foo, array[x::int] AS bar
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS x
);
CREATE INDEX test_foo ON test (foo);
CREATE INDEX test_bar ON test (bar);
VACUUM ANALYZE test;
```

So now these work as expected

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo = 10000;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE bar = array[10000];
```

But, this does not use the index.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE bar @> array[10000];
```

So you need a `GIN` index, and now this will work.

```
CREATE INDEX test_gin ON test USING GIN (bar);
```

So let's review now the sizes of the indexes.

```
              List of relations
         Name    | Type  |  Table  |  Size
 test_bar        | index | test    | 47 MB
 test_gin        | index | test    | 53 MB
 test_foo        | index | test    | 21 MB
```

So two points,

1. **You need a GIN index to make use of array operators.**
2. You don't need a b-tree index (don't create it).
3. GIN indexes are substantially larger than indexes on `INT` columns
4. GIN indexes are somewhat slower to update.

Just more things to consider.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps another thing to consider is that if those integers refer to primary keys in another table `tags_tag`, using a proper through-table with a primary key and two foreign keys of its own would turn the tables (excuse the pun), wouldn't it?

Comment: I doubt the overheads introduced by the indexes overcome to overhead of the table join. Use the arrays if they make sense. Nothing wrong with them.